# Initialize jQuery Plugin property with a function instead of a static property?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I would like to initialize a jQuery plugin with a function instead of a static property.
It works like this:

```
$("#sliderPrice").slider({
    step: 1,
    smooth: true,
    limits: false,
    scale:  ['24h', '48h', '3&nbsp;days', '1&nbsp;week']
});
```

What I'm trying to do is this:

```
$("#sliderPrice").slider({
    step: 1,
    smooth: true,
    limits: false,
    scale:  function(){ return some custom array; }
});
```

Is that somehow possible?
I'm using the [Slider](http://blog.egorkhmelev.com/2009/11/jquery-slider-safari-style/) from Egor Khmelev.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just `self-invoke` a function without modifying the original code:

```
$("#sliderPrice").slider({
    step: 1,
    smooth: true,
    limits: false,
    scale:  (function(){
       return [5,4,3,2,1];
    }())
});
```

You can basically do anything within that self-invoking anonymous function. Create, modify or map an existent array and finally return it. The outer parenthesis aren't necessary, but it's a convenient way to tell anybody who is looking at your code, that something is going on there.